# EJB lookup fails in JAAS LoginModule

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, jaas, undertow

I am updating an application which uses a custom `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule` to authenticate users via FORM authentication to run on WildFly 17. This login module validates credentials by calling a method on a remote stateless EJB.

The remote EJB connection is defined at the server level in the remoting subsystem, as described on https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance e.g. in the JBoss CLI: `/subsystem=remoting/remote-outbound-connection=my-connection:add(outbound-socket-binding-ref=my-socket-binding-ref, protocol=http-remoting, security-realm=ejb-security-realm, username=ejb-user)`

Outside the LoginModule (elsewhere in the application), the EJB lookup is successful with the following:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory" );
properties.put( Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming" );
InitialContext context = new InitialContext( properties );

UserRepository remoteUserRepository = (UserRepository)context.lookup( "ejb:application-ear/application-ejb//BeanName!my.package.UserRepository" );
```

Running under WildFly 9, the same lookup succeeded inside the LoginModule, however in WildFly 17 the lookup fails with the following trace:

```
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079: Unable to discover destination for request for EJB StatelessEJBLocator for "application-ear/application-ejb/BeanName", view is interface my.package.UserRepository, affinity is None
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:607)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:543)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:609)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:543)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:148)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:609)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:543)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:609)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:543)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:609)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:543)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:212)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:609)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:543)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:963)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.20.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:125)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.validateClientCompatibility(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//my.package.UserRepositoryLoginModule.initialize(UserRepositoryLoginModule.java:)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:716)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:665)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:663)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:663)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:574)
    at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:406)
    at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345)
    at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:323)
    at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verifyCredential(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:123)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verify(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:94)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.login(SecurityContextImpl.java:198)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.login(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:482)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//my.package.LoginBean.loginUser(LoginBean.java:)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//my.package.LoginBean.attemptLogin(LoginBean.java:)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:280)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1//javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1.29-11//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1//javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1.29-11//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1.29-11//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1.29-11//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:603)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//my.package.LoginPageRedirectionFilter.doFilter(LoginPageRedirectionFilter.java:)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
07/24/2019 09:53:43,966 [ERROR] [default task-2] [my.package.LoginBean] - Unexpected error signing user in
javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.login(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:490)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//my.package.LoginBean.loginUser(LoginBean.java:)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//my.package.LoginBean.attemptLogin(LoginBean.java:)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:280)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1//javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1.29-11//com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1//javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1.29-11//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1.29-11//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1.29-11//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.1.29-11@2.1//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:603)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.application-ear.ear.application-war.war//my.package.LoginPageRedirectionFilter.doFilter(LoginPageRedirectionFilter.java:)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Is something additional necessary, or is there a workaround, so the custom LoginModule may perform remote EJB lookups which have the destination server defined in the client's server?

Comment: Is this EJB in the same EAR that is secured by the JAAS Login module? If so you will have a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @SteveC No it is not. The JAAS LoginModule is securing an application in a separate EAR from the user repository EJB.